# How to fix pylance syntax highlighting showing wrong color for self and cls python class parameters in VSCode with enabled default theme

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, themes, syntax-highlighting, pylance

I have encountered this issue when I use Pylance and syntax highlighting is enabled for python in the VSCode with default or the visual studio theme.

self and cls parameter are LightSkyBlue color like other parameters
[image: before]

It should be like this:

[image: should be this]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Added the color code inside the `settings.json` file for the dark themes I use.

```json
// correct color self and cls python
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
        "rules": {
            "selfParameter": "#569CD6",
            "clsParameter": "#569CD6"
        },
    },
    "[Visual Studio Dark]": {
        "rules": {
            "selfParameter": "#569CD6",
            "clsParameter": "#569CD6"
        },
    },
    "[Default Dark Modern]": {
        "rules": {
            "selfParameter": "#569CD6",
            "clsParameter": "#569CD6"
        },
    }
},
```

Add theme settings based on what theme you are using. for example, I just changed my theme to [Default Dark Modern] and then added the color settings.

These two issues on pylance and vscode github repository helped:

- https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/323
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/118946

Comment: This doesnt seem to work on latest visual studio and pylance, with the error: `Property rules is not allowed.`

Comment: @Nanyo thank you for the comment. I checked it on my VSCode. The setting config still works for me and if I remove it, it will make `self` and `cls` LightSkyBlue color again.
VSCODE Version = February 2022 (version 1.65)
Pylance Version = v2022.3.2

Comment: @Nanyo did you hit the same issue I did, putting this in "workbench.colorCustomizations" and not "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations" as is in this answer?

Comment: @seaders Yes, that was exactly what I did. A bit silly but still new to all this :)

Comment: I am using VSCode 1.80 (June 2023), and I am facing the issue that if I have my Python extension enabled, it immediately overwrites the coloring to the default one. Have you faced that?

Comment: @SBF No. Did you add the settings for your active theme? I just edited the answer.

Comment: @PedramElmi you mean, did I specify that this to be applied to a specific theme in the settings.json?